# Shell script syntax - adding quote to end of line

Tags: shell, scripting

I have below script which gives me syntax error if I add the single quote at the end of the line where I am assigning the java vm arguments. Why this syntax is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Incorrect

JVM_OPTS='-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms250M -Xmx250M -Xss1M  -DVAR1='"$VALUE1"' -DVAR2='"$VALUE2"'
START_CMD="java ${JVM_OPTS} ${JVM_ARGS} -jar ${1}"
$START_CMD

#!/bin/bash

#Correct

JVM_OPTS='-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms250M -Xmx250M -Xss1M  -DVAR1='"$VALUE1"' -DVAR2='"$VALUE2"
START_CMD="java ${JVM_OPTS} ${JVM_ARGS} -jar ${1}"
$START_CMD
```

Comment: How does `JVM_OPTS` get used? It should *probably* be an array, not a regular parameter, and if that's not possible, you may be limited in what options you can actually provide unless `eval` is involved in some fashion.

Comment: The "correct" version is not a single quoted string; it is multiple strings (some in `'...'`, others in `"...") *concatenated* into a single value.

Comment: I hesitated to call it correct, as it seems to assume that `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` don't need to be quoted once `JVM_OPTS` itself is expanded.

Comment: @chepner updated to show usage

Comment: read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's match the start and end quotes:

```
JVM_OPTS='-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms250M -Xmx250M -Xss1M  -DVAR1='"$VALUE1"' -DVAR2='"$VALUE2"'
#        \............................................../\......./\......../\......./^
```

You have an unmatched quote.

But use @chepner's suggestions. Building up a command into a single string is bound to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an array (and/or a function)

```
JVM_OPTS=(-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms250M -Xmx250M -Xss1M  -DVAR1="$VALUE1" -DVAR2="$VALUE2")
JVM_ARGS=(...)

start_cmd () {
    java "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" "${JVM_ARGS[@]}" -jar "$1"
}

start_cmd "$1"
```